# Existe substituto para o ClickOnce do .NET?

Tags: .net, deploy, instalador, clickonce

O ClickOnce nunca foi considerado uma maravilha por alguns, mas pra mim está mais complicado de usar com .NET ultimamente. Ainda existem aplicações que seria interessante ter uma forma simples de instalar e resolver tudo o que precisa.

Nunca fizeram alguma coisa melhor?

Comment: Não entendi a sua afirmação: complicado utilizar com .NET, porque isso não faz o menor sentido. Até hoje a documentação bem atual utilizando .NET e .NET CORE. Exemplo: (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2022)[Implantar um aplicativo da área de trabalho .NET Framework usando o assistente de Publicação do ClickOnce]. Eu utilizo até hoje e não é nada complicado essa solução.

Comment: Estou colocando uma situação possível de alguém, pode ter ficado para a pessoa dentro das necessidades dela, não é necessariamente crítica ao produto ter piorado. É uma pergunta, que geralmente mantém dúvidas e não respostas.

Comment: A sua primeira linha faz criticas ao ClickOnce e a segunda linha diz o que o ClickOnce tem como objetivo principal, que é a facilidade de instalar aplicativos com atualizações e é muito fácil utilizar esse cara e funciona muito bem. Agora se a pergunta fosse se tem outras soluções eu até acho que é uma boa pergunta do jeito que está não é!

Comment: Que bom que sempre foi ótimo para você. As pessoas vivem reclamando que instalação é um problema e vão pra web, se os instaladores são tão bons não deveria ter esse argumento.

Comment: Ai é um argumento dos que reclamam, falta de conhecimento, não sei, mas, ir para Web não deveria ser por causa disso. Desculpas mas, a sua pergunta está mau formulado, porque dizer que ficou mais complicado é mais opinião do que realidade.

Comment: Perguntas costumam ser assim, novamente, por isso é uma pergunta, e não uma resposta. Não vou entrar na questão do desconhecimento porque isso pode ser opinativo, e o oposto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu conheci recentemente o [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel). Ainda não o usei, mas parece interessante. Além dele prometer que funciona, até mesmo com aplicações desktop de outros tipos. Embora pareça limitado para desktop, é o público-alvo, não costuma precisar para outras coisas.

O que eu achei mais interessante é ter todo o processo de administração de forma simples, incluindo a atualização da aplicação da maneira correta sem que o usuário precise se preocupar.

Além disso ele faz o processo necessário para a "instalação" sem exigir privilégio. E tudo ocorre de forma mais simples.

Ou seja, dá para evitar os problemas que as pessoas falam que aplicação desktop tem e ainda ter as vantagens dela, por exemplo de rodar em um ambiente operacional mais estável que a web, que muda todo mês e nem sempre respeita a compatibilidade. Você controla todo processo de atualização dele, e resolve as dependências.

Se ele não atender algum detalhe, não parece ser difícil modificar o código, ou até mesmo servir de base para algo mais ambicioso.

Uma pena ser pouco documentado.

Engenheiros acham solução para tudo, a não ser que não seja possível solucionar. Em alguns casos a solução já existe pronta.